# Difference between specific syntax when doing comparison

Tags: javascript

When I want to compare two strings for example, or other stuff, I'll do (This is also what I see other people do most of the time)

```
if(someStringVar != "") { //Do something }
```

or

`if(session == null) {...}`

But in some rare occasions, I see some people do (And this always hurts my eyes, as it doesn't make much sense to me)

```
if("" != someStringVar) { //Do something }
```

or

```
if(null == session )
```

Now I have decided to figure out if this is only about personal preference, or if there actually are some cases where it would be smarter to do the part that hurts my eyes.
If there are benefits, some examples would be nice. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's personal preference, nothing more.

Comment: That's used to avoid typos : `if (session = null)` is valid syntax but won't give you the expected behavior. `if (null = session)` is a syntax error so you can fix your typo easier